# Wrongly initialized Cursor?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have to write a simple program which lets you choose a contact from your contact list and shows the name, number and the picture of it. The only thing i get though is an Cursor error. I'll give the code and the lof from LogCat. I was trying to put 0 instead of 
  cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME) and 1 instead of cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER), but i get NullPointerException. Any ideas? Thanks.

Program:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_Contact_Request = 0;
TextView textView1, textView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onUpdateContact(View v)
{
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), PICK_Contact_Request);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == PICK_Contact_Request)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                cursor = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
                int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
                String id = cursor.getString(idx);

                int phoneX;
                String phoneNumber = null;

                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, BaseColumns._ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    pCur.moveToFirst();
                    phoneX = pCur.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    phoneNumber = pCur.getString(phoneX);
                    pCur.close();
                }
                cursor.close();

                textView1.setText(name);
                textView2.setText(phoneNumber);
                img.setImageResource(photoIdIdx);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/contact_name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/contact_phone" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
     android:textSize="12sp" 
     android:layout_below="@id/contact_name" 
     android:layout_alignLeft="@id/contact_name"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/contact_portrait"
    android:contentDescription="@string/zdjecie"
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:background="#aaa" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/contact_name" 
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/update_contact_button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/updateContact" 
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_portrait" 
    android:onClick="onUpdateContact" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

LogCat:

```
Null Pointer Exception @ line 75: text1.setText(name); and 76 text2.setText(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: your query din't succeed . `col -1` in stacktrace indicates that.

Comment: The problem is i tried like 3 slightly different codes and I get the same error all the time. The program works fine till I choose a contact from the list. I've changed the program now so that it doesn't just crach but handles the exception - still can't manage to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably trying to use the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` column, since the column is not part of this table, getColumnIndex() will return -1 for it. This information needs to be queried separately (having checked the value of the `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` column first).

See the "Phone Numbers" section in this tutorial: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

**UPDATE**
There are at least a couple of problems with your new code:

- Missing moveToFirst() before trying to read values, for both cursors.
- Cursor is being closed before reading HAS_PHONE_NUMBER.
- The id column name constant should be BaseColumns._ID, not Phone.CONTACT_ID.

Comment: I've managed to alter the code accordingly to the given tutorial. Thank you, but still something is wrong.

Comment: @user3582469 Updated answer with new issues detected.

Comment: Seems like I don't get any data from my queries, but I checked it and there is data. Have no idea what's going on.